# Spring Integration - publishSubscribeChannel aggregate after split

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have a DSL-based flow that uses `split` to iterate over a list of objects and send out a Kafka message:

```
.transform(...)
.split()
.channel(KAFKA_OUT_CHANNEL)
```

After all the messages have been sent out, I need to call a service and I also need to log how many messages were processed.
I understand that an approach is to use a `publishSubscribeChannel` where the first `subscribe` does that actual Kafka sending and then the `aggregate` execute the service call:

```
.transform(...)
.split().
.publishSubscribeChannel(pubSub -> pubSub
        .subscribe(f -> f.channel(KAFKA_OUT_CHANNEL)))
```

I'm having problems figuring out how to actually do the `.aggregate` part within a pubSubChannel using the DSL. So far I have tried:

```
.subscribe(f ->  f.channel(KAFKA_OUT_CHANNEL)
.subscribe(f -> f.aggregate(c -> c.processor( ?? ))))
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

The `AbstractMessageSplitter` has an `applySequence = true` by default:

```
/**
 * Set the applySequence flag to the specified value. Defaults to true.
 * @param applySequence true to apply sequence information.
 */
public void setApplySequence(boolean applySequence) {
```

With that we have in the messages these headers:

```
if (this.applySequence) {
    builder.pushSequenceDetails(correlationId, sequenceNumber, sequenceSize);
}
```

The Aggregator's default correlation strategy is really based on the `IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.CORRELATION_ID` header. This way it gathers messages with the same `correlationKey` into the same `MessageGroup`. The default `ReleaseStrategy` is based on the `MessageGroup` and that `sequenceSize` header comparison. In the end the default `MessageGroupProcessor` just collect all the messages in the group into a single message with the `Collection` as a payload. In other words the default behavior of the aggregator is absolutely opposite to the splitter.

I don't know what the output you are going to do from the aggregator, but you don't need any other logic to configure there - correlation and releasing logic should be based on the default state.

You can find enough info in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator).

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want after the aggregation - if you just want a list of payloads, just use `aggregate()`...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So51059703Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So51059703Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(ApplicationContext context) {
        return args -> {
            context.getBean("flow.input", MessageChannel.class).send(new GenericMessage<>(
                    Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c")));
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow() {
        return f -> f
                .split()
                .publishSubscribeChannel(p -> p
                        .subscribe(f1 -> f1.handle(System.out::println))
                        .subscribe(f2 -> f2
                                .aggregate()
                                .handle(System.out::println)));
    }

}
```

If you just want the count:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So51059703Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So51059703Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(ApplicationContext context) {
        return args -> {
            context.getBean("flow.input", MessageChannel.class).send(new GenericMessage<>(
                    Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c")));
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow() {
        return f -> f
                .split()
                .publishSubscribeChannel(p -> p
                        .subscribe(f1 -> f1.handle(System.out::println))
                        .subscribe(f2 -> f2
                                .aggregate(c -> c
                                        .processor(processor(), "reduce"))
                                .handle(System.out::println)));
    }

    @Bean
    public Object processor() {
        return new Object() {

            public int reduce(List<Message<?>> messages) {
                return messages.size();
            }

        };
    }

}
```